# Cordova android plugin not registering the js object to window

Tags: android, cordova

I am writing a Cordova plugin for Android, and it is not registering a JavaScript object to `window` and I would like to know why.

In the plugin's `plugin.xml`, I am using `<js-module>` to register the js object to `window` object:

```
  <platform name="android">
    <js-module src="www/Loading.js" name="loader">
      <clobbers target="loader" />
    </js-module>
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="Loading">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.loader.Loading" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
      </feature>
    </config-file>
    ...
  </platform>
```

The plugin compiles, but when I do `window.loader` in Chrome debugger, it is undefined. I tried changing the value of `target` in `<clobbers>` to `window.loader` to no avail.

`www/Loading.js` file is exporting a JavaScript object using `module.exports`:

```
function Loading() {
  ...
}
module.exports = new Loading();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. This is a very specific case for my app. I am copying everything from the sandboxed environment to an internal path and booting the app from the internal path. Turns out the app was not copying the `www/Loader.js` file.